# Sample of payment update in Quickbook PHP

Tags: quickbooks

I am using the open-source QuickBooks PHP DevKit on GitHub. I treid to update payment. But it showing error. Please give any sample of payment update.

Comment: Specifically what error is it showing?

Comment: This the Error I am getting ""ERROR!2030: [Invalid ID, Id should be a valid number. Supplied value:{-17}]". Please see the code I used for updating the payment is this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182129/update-payment-in-open-source-quickbooks-php-devkit-on-github.